# OpenShift Node.js CERT_UNTRUSTED

Tags: node.js, certificate

Note: this has nothing to do with NPM (which is what comes up the most when googling this error):

I have a Node server which is trying to make https calls to a IIS/.Net server. My understanding is that when my Node server is playing the part of the "client" I don't need to attach any certificates to the options (var Request = Https.request(Options, function(Response) { ... }); ), however, recently when the IIS/.Net server updated its certificates, Node started throwing CERT_UNTRUSTED errors.

The obvious culprit is the IIS.Net server and/or its certificates, however, that server can be successfully reached by non-Node servers (or fiddler, for example).

The other oddity is that all this code was working fine till the certificates on the IIs.Net server expired and were reset.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work correctly from your local development environment (your computer) vs on openshift?  That would be helpful to know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on either.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work using the answer found at a similar post:
[Unable to verify leaf signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature/22263280#22263280)

Still not sure why renewing the certificates caused this to happen, but either way, the ssl-root-cas/latest module did the trick.