# Node Js: Error - Unable to verify leaf signature when installing Express Framework

Tags: node.js, express

I need to install Express Framework for my application.
This is the error which I am obtaining. I tried to set Environment varaibales for my computer towards npm as http://username:password@proxy:port for both http and https.

Also, I have tried the code such as

```
npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxy:port -g
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy:port -g
npm config set strict-ssl false.
```

Even then I am getting the below error.

```
 npm ERR! node v0.12.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
    npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

    npm ERR! unable to verify the first certificate
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Any help regarding installing Express Framework would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature

Answer (score 8):

I have also faced same problem, but your last option i.e.

`npm config set strict-ssl false`  worked for me.

after run this command in command prompt I installed express framework with following command:

`npm install -g express-generator`

Answer (score 0):

Even I got the same error while installing angular cli...
I have used the command `npm config set strict-ssl false` in cmd and then installed using `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

It worked...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`npm config set strict-ssl false` should fix it.

Comment: Could you add an explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was in a docker environment and I did not copied the `.yarnrc` that included the `sstrict-ssl false` directive to the image in the build phase.

Answer (score 0):

Issue:

```
>npm install
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@webassemblyjs/ieee754/-/ieee754-1.7.6.tgz failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Solution:

`npm install` worked after executing this command:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```