# Get token oAuth using npm

Tags: javascript, oauth, npm

I'm trying to develop a service using nodeJS that retrieve a token OAuth from a server. But I have every time an error.
this the function.

```
var express = require('express')
var http = require('http');
var httpRequest = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express()

app.get('/get-token', function (request, response) {

  // Ask for token
  httpRequest({
      url: 'https://my-server.com/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'Authorization': 'Basic SdfdhffhPeHVBTV84OExfVWFmR1cwMklh'
      },
      form: {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'myLogin',
        'password': 'myPwd',
      }
    }, function(error, response, body){
      if(error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log(response.statusCode, body);
      }
  });

});
```

When I make a request, the server return this error:

```
{ [Error: unable to verify the first certificate] code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

Would you have an idea how I can process or if there is a package npm that make the same job ?

Best regards

Comment: Does this help you? [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature)

Comment: Thanks @Antii I resolve the problem by adding this ==> rejectUnauthorized: false  in options

Answer (score 0):

This wokrks for me

```
...  
  app.get('/get-token', function (request, response) {

      // Ask for token
      httpRequest({
          rejectUnauthorized: false,
          url: 'https://my-server.com/token',
     ...
```