# node + plesk + ssl : how to make them run together?

Tags: node.js, ssl, plesk

My client's websites runs a ssl generated by PLESK.

I used to run node.js with SSL thanks to:

```
var ssl = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite/cert.pem')
};
```

But I have no idea where PLESK did create these 2 files.

I tried with:

```
> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
> /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

With no success.

Any idea on how to run nodejs with SSL generated by Plesk ?

Comment: Take a look at `/usr/local/psa/var/certificates/` ?

Comment: yes: there are 2 files there but still have the same error: Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE

Comment: @yarek as I see this error means that certificates are valid but untrusted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature

Answer (score 3):

Pls. note, that Let's Encrypt certificates, created over the Plesk Let's Encrypt extension, place their original certificate files at:

```html
/usr/local/psa/var/modules/letsencrypt/etc/live/(sub)YOUR-DOMAIN.COM
```

... while these files are symlinks to the archive of all created Let's Encrypt certificates and these symlinks will always link to the latest ( and actual valid ) certifiate files ( pls. remember, that Let's Encrypt certificates are only valid for a maximum of 90 days! ).

In addition, pls. note as well, that you should use the "fullchain.pem" and not the "cert.pem", because the "cert.pem" misses the needed root certificate. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the NodeJS extension for Plesk (version Onyx) and the LetsEncrypt Extension to handle the verification, routing and automatic renewal of your Certificates. That Way you can to everything in the Plesk web interface and don't even have to use the console.

1. [Install Git Extension](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/ad09122e-0f57-49ba-b06c-847b735158af-git)
2. [Install NodeJS Extension](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/node-js/)
3. [Install LetsEncrypt](https://www.plesk.com/extensions/letsencrypt/)
4. configure Git and NodeJS for your Domain in Plesk

   1. including a public folder that is accessible through your Node App (Document Root)
   2. set the PORT your app is listening on to `process.env.PORT`
5. activate LetsEncrypt for that Domain
6. done!

For more Details check out the Tutorial by Plesk:
https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/.

Answer (score 0):

For example you have domain `example.tld` with Let's Encrypt certificate name `Lets Encrypt example.tld`. You can download certificate file with private key from Plesk UI:

[image: plesk letsencrypt SSL]

Or you may try to find this certificate files by following request:

```
# mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -Dpsa -e "select id, cert_file, ca_file, name from certificates where name like '%example%'"
+----+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | cert_file   | ca_file     | name                                         |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
|  3 | cert-1lPfuj | cert-6oXdCf | Lets Encrypt example.tld                     |
+----+-------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

and as @El_Matella said check files `cert-1lPfuj` and `cert-6oXdCf` at `/usr/local/psa/var/certificates`:

```
# ls -la /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-*
-r--------. 1 root root 5050 Jan  1 02:33 /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-1lPfuj
-r--------. 1 root root 1635 Jan  1 02:33 /usr/local/psa/var/certificates/cert-6oXdCf
```