# heroku login unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

I'm trying login to my heroku account but getting error

```
D:\rails-app>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: dsfdsf@gamil.com
Password: ********
 !    UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Log-file %LOCALAPPDATA%\heroku\error.log

```
  Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1104:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:638:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:468:38)
2017/11/02 11:02:51
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature#20100521

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all the old installations of Heroku gem by :

- Try running heroku update first and see if the issue is resolved
  otherwise try this
- gem uninstall heroku ( uninstall the toolbelt. )
- Install the Heroku toolbelt again.