# Unable to verify the first certificate - Nodejs TLS

Tags: node.js, ssl, tls1.2, ftps

I'm using the node-module [basic-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-ftp) to try to establish a secure connection via [TLS/ SSL](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html). 
The server uses a wildcard CA-signed certificate as it's hostname. I can't seem to find an answer for the followig error code.

```
Connected to 1.1.1.1:21
< 220 Welcome to ftp.foo.com  
> AUTH TLS 
< 234 Using authentication type TLS
{ Error: unable to verify the first certificate
   at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)
   at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
   at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' 
}
```

Below you find the sample code:

```
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");

async establishFtpsConnection() {
    const client = new ftp.Client();
    client.ftp.verbose = true;

    try {
        await client.access({
            host: "ftp.foo.com",
            user: "bar",
            password: "1234",
            port: 21,
            secure: true
        });

        const list = await client.list();
        console.log(list);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    client.close();
}
```

NOTE: I'm trying to get it to work for my production environment. So disabling or rejecting unauthorization is **NO** option for me.

```
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';
```

OR

```
rejectUnauthorized: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const ftp = require("basic-ftp");

async establishFtpsConnection() {
    const client = new ftp.Client();
    client.ftp.verbose = true;
    const tlsOptions = {
            cert: fs.readFileSync('fullchain.pem', 'ascii')
             // a PEM containing the SERVER and ALL INTERMEDIATES
           }


    try {
        await client.access({
            host: "ftp.foo.com",
            user: "bar",
            password: "1234",
            port: 21,
            secure: true,
           secureOptions:tlsOptions
        });

        const list = await client.list();
        console.log(list);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    client.close();
}
```

If you are still getting an error then try to inject root SSL certificates

```
var sslRootCAs = require('ssl-root-cas/latest')
sslRootCAs.inject()
```

Comment: read more here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I've also tried manually including the intermediate certificate as explained in the [API](https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/ssl-root-cas.js#unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate). 
`.addFile(__dirname + '/ssl/01-cheap-ssl-intermediary-a.pem')`

Comment: In my case the user individually configures multiple ftp connections via userinterface. So uploading and providing each and every certificate separately isn't really what I had in mind. Am I missing the point and should it be handled that way?

Comment: If I am not wrong, what we are passing here is a server certificate with a full chain of certificates. so the same certificate should work for all users and I think this is how it should be.

Comment: What do you mean by "a server certificate with a full chain of certificates"? Users create various ftp connections, so for every connection I'll have to manually add a server certificate with it's chain certificates?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
await client.access({
        protocol: "ftp",
        host: "",
        user: "",
        password: "",
        port: 21,
        secure: true,
        secureOptions: {"rejectUnauthorized":false}
    });
```