# Lets-encrypt Error: Failed HTTP-01 Pre-Flight / Dry Run

Tags: lets-encrypt, redbird

I've set up a redbird based proxy following its [README file examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redbird).

By now I've configured single domain both for http and https and it's working well (https still using self-signed certificate).

But now I'm trying to configure it to use letsencrypt to automatically get valid ssl certificates and I'm getting stuck in following error:

```
 {"level":30,"time":1578681102208,"pid":21320,"hostname":"nigul","name":"redbird","0":false,"1":"setChallenge called for 'exposito.bitifet.net'","msg":"Lets encrypt debugger","v":1}
[acme-v2] handled(?) rejection as errback:
Error: Error: Failed HTTP-01 Pre-Flight / Dry Run.
curl 'http://exposito.bitifet.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-cf55199519d859042f695e620cca8dbb-0'
Expected: 'test-cf55199519d859042f695e620cca8dbb-0.MgLl7GIS59DPtPMejuUcXfddzNt8YxfLVo5op670u8M'
Got: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
'
See https://git.coolaj86.com/coolaj86/acme-v2.js/issues/4
    at /home/joanmi/SERVICES/redbird_domains/node_modules/acme-v2/index.js:49:10
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

As far as I understand, this is telling me that Lets Encrypt is trying to access to the url http://exposito.bitifet.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-cf55199519d859042f695e620cca8dbb-0 using the following command:

```
curl 'http://exposito.bitifet.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-cf55199519d859042f695e620cca8dbb-0'
```

...and that it is getting which seems a 404 HTML Error page which I have no clue wherever it could come.

And, in fact, executing that *curl* command or just pasting [that url](http://exposito.bitifet.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/test-cf55199519d859042f695e620cca8dbb-0) in my browser (you can try it: I left the server running), I get the given *Expected* string so, from my point of view it seems like if my configuration were correct but, for some reason, Lets Encrypt's servers were reaching another server (either because of wrong routing or DNS).

But on the other hand, I suppose it's more probable that I've done something wrong in my configuration.

Here I paste my whole script (ports 80 and 443 are redirected to 1080 and 1443, respectively, through iptables because the script is run by non privileged user):

```
const Redbird = require("redbird");

const proxy = Redbird({
    port: 1080,
    xfwd: false, // Disable the X-Forwarded-For header
    letsencrypt: {
    path: __dirname + '/certs',
    port: 9999
            // LetsEncrypt minimal web server port for handling challenges.
            // Routed 80->9999, no need to open 9999 in firewall. Default 3000
            // if not defined.
    },
    ssl: {
        http2: true,
        port: 1443, // SSL port used to serve registered https routes with LetsEncrypt certificate.
    }

});


proxy.register('exposito.bitifet.net:9999', 'http://localhost:8001', {
  ssl: {
    letsencrypt: {
      email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', // Domain owner/admin email
      production: false,
                // WARNING: Only use this flag when the proxy is verified to
                // work correctly to avoid being banned!
    }
  }
});

proxy.register("exposito.bitifet.net", "http://localhost:8001");
```

Any clue will be welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!!**

Many issues were involved at the same time (despite my lack of experience with either redbird and letsencrypt.

1. **The *magic* 404/Not found page:** I guess it came from a *lighttpd* server that seems to had been preinstalled in my VPS.

Port 80 was redirected via iptables but I suppose in one or other configuration tweak I could have redirected incoming requests to **localhost**'s port 80 (which is not redirected).

2. **My redbird missunderstanding:** Looking at examples in its README file, I thought redbird were kinda "**multi-** reverse_proxy" in the sense that you could redirect http and https requests with single redbird instance.

But I finally realized that the (maybe not so well named) *port* option which is, in fact, an http port, serves only to configure a built-in unconditional http->https redirector (of which I already had read about, but I thought it were optional).

3. **The actual underlying issue:** If your DNS have DNSSEC activated, you should define a *CAA* register in it pointing to *letsencrypt.org*.

At the moment I disabled DNSSEC instead because my provider's control panel doesn't allow me to create such register.

I discovered it while trying to get the certificates through *certbot* (`sudo apt-get install certbot` which I must say that, If I had known about it before, I wouldn't had care about trying redbird's letsencrypt integration.

It is much more verbose (while redbird is more like a black box when errors arise) and pointed out that I needed the CAA register.

Here the notes I took about it (in case anyone could be interested):

```
Free SSL Certificates with Certbot
    Install certbot:
        sudo apt-get install certbot
    Create:
        sudo certbot certonly --manual --preferred-challenges http -d <domain>
    Renew:
        sudo certbot renew
    Caveats:
        DNSSEC
            If your DNS server has DNSSEC enabled, you will need to add a CAA
            register pointing to letsencrypt.org.
            ...and your DNS provider my not allow to create it (at least I
            couldn't with CDMON. Also not -yet- complained).
```

4. **`production = false` is for other kinds of testing:** I read that if you put in to *true* while testing, you may be banned from letsencrypt if you perform too many requests.

Setting it to false you can test redirections, but you will see still errors regarding letsencrypt even you could navigate **without** a secure certificate (I think kinda self-signed is provided to allow testing). So don't expect a valid one.

5. **ssl port is used for redirection:** Not a (big) issue, but if you specify ssl port other than 443, built in redirector will unconditionally redirect you to that port.

Running redbird as root and using standard (80 and 443) ports works fine. But if you, like me, want to use an alternative ports in order to execute redbird with non privileged user, you will get redirected to that alternative port instead of 443 (Even having it redirected through iptables).

---

Here my (almost*) final redbird script:

```
const Redbird = require("redbird");

const proxy = Redbird({
    port: 1080,
    xfwd: false, // Disable the X-Forwarded-For header
    ssl: {
        port: 1443,
    },
    letsencrypt: {
        path: __dirname + '/certs',
        port: 9999,
                // LetsEncrypt minimal web server port for handling challenges.
                // Routed 80->9999, no need to open 9999 in firewall. Default 3000
                // if not defined.
    },

});

proxy.register('exposito.bitifet.net', 'http://exposito.bitifet.net:8001', {
    ssl: {
        http2: true,
        letsencrypt: {
          email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', // Domain owner/admin email
          production: true,
                    // WARNING: Only use this flag when the proxy is verified to
                    // work correctly to avoid being banned!

        },
    }
});
```

(*) I still need to fix the explicit-port redirection issue (5), because I don't want to run redbird as root. But I know is possible to allow uses to listen given ports. Even I would probably better try to patch redbird in order to allow specifying listen and redirection ports separatedly.

**EDIT:** It is already implemented (and documented) using the (optional) option *redirectPort* in *ssl* section. Just added `redirectPort: 443` and job done!!

**EDIT 2:** For the sake of completion, there still was another issue I struggled with.

To get things working I finally configured the redirection to the http port instead of https one.

That is: Incomming https requests gets redirected to my application http port.

It seems weird but it works. At least if you don't need any exclusively https feature such as push notifications (which I plan to use in the future).

But its implies to open an http server **at least** on localhost. Which isn't a major issue now (this is only a playground server) but I plan to use redbird at work to proxy multiple domains to different servers so that would had forced us to open http at least in our DMZ vlan (which is an additional risk that is better to avoid...).

When I tried redirecting to https I got the DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error.

Ok: This is telling me that redbird (or node) does not trust my original (self signed) certificate. I know there is an option to tell node to accept those certificates. But maybe it is not the way to go...

So I configured my application to use the same certificate that redbird is obtaining through letsencrypt.

But then I got this other error:

```
UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
```

Researching a bit I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59475494/4243912) that explains how to get *all root and intermediate certificates trusted by Mozilla* and make node to trust them.

So, at the end, what I did was:

1. Installed *node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle* package:

   ```
   npm install --save node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle
   ```
2. Prepended `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=node_modules/node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle/ca_bundle/ca_intermediate_root_bundle.pem` to the *start* command in the *package.json*'s *scripts* section.
3. Updated my redbird script to point again to the https (protocol and) port:

   ```
   proxy.register('exposito.bitifet.net', 'https://localhost:4301', {...]);
   ```

Here my final redbird configuration:

```
const Redbird = require("redbird");

const proxy = Redbird({
    port: 1080,
    xfwd: false, // Disable the X-Forwarded-For header
    ssl: {
        port: 1443,
        redirectPort: 443
        // key: "/etc/bitifet/exposito/ssl/private.key",
        // cert: "/etc/bitifet/exposito/ssl/public.cert",
    },
    letsencrypt: {
        path: __dirname + '/certs',
        port: 9999,
                // LetsEncrypt minimal web server port for handling challenges.
                // Routed 80->9999, no need to open 9999 in firewall. Default 3000
                // if not defined.
    },

});

proxy.register('exposito.bitifet.net', 'https://localhost:4301', {
    ssl: {
        http2: true,
        letsencrypt: {
          email: 'xxxxxx@gmail.com', // Domain owner/admin email
          production: true,
                    // WARNING: Only use this flag when the proxy is verified to
                    // work correctly to avoid being banned!

        },
    }
});
```

And here my *package.json* file contents:

```
{
  "name": "redbird_domains",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Local Domains Handling",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=node_modules/node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle/ca_bundle/ca_intermediate_root_bundle.pem node ./index.js"
  },
  "author": "Joanmi",
  "license": "GPL-3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "node_extra_ca_certs_mozilla_bundle": "^1.0.4",
    "redbird": "^0.10.0"
  }
}
```