# Request to API fails, reason: unable to verify the first certificate (and UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE)

Tags: node.js, ssl, apollo, apollo-server

We have an Apollo Server which is calling an external API (which translates the REST API into GraphQL).  Up until several days ago this worked fine, using `cross-fetch` to call the API.

On Friday we started getting the following error (below).  I've done some searching and it seems to have to do with certificates (see [Error: unable to verify the first certificate in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs) for example).  Following the answer to that question, I tried using `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssl-root-cas` and putting

```
require('https').globalAgent.options.ca = require('ssl-root-cas/latest').create();
```

at the start of my code, but that didn't seem to work.

More importantly, I'm unclear what I'm doing.  I have a *general* idea of what certificates are, how they work, but in this context I'm unclear why I'm having to provide a certificate to a public API that didn't want one a few days ago. In other words, while I want to solve it, I'd also to understand what is going on here as well.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "request to https://www.someapi.com failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate",
      "locations": [],
      "path": [
        "someSearch"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "message": "request to https://www.someapi.com failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate",
          "type": "system",
          "errno": "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE",
          "code": "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE",
          "stacktrace": [
            "FetchError: request to https://www.someapi.com failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate",
            "    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/Documents/projects/yaa-interface-new/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1455:11)",
            "    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)",
            "    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)",
            "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)",
            "    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)",
            "    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "someSearch": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work --

First I downloaded the chain PEM certificate, inspired by the 4th answer here: [Unable to verify leaf signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature).

Then I used [NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file), pointing to the downloaded PEM file.

`NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS='./something-chain.pem' node index.js`

That worked fine.

Comment: The order of answers, and even posters' names can change over time, making "4th answer" link misleading with very high probability. Please next time use permalinks which can be obtained by tapping "share" button below the specific answer.