# Axios error unable to verify leaf signature

Tags: reactjs, axios

i applied to use a dictionary API and it was asked the URL which i would be using it, i choosed locahost:19006, because it's where the local server is opening. And i have the API key, but for some reason i'm having CORS issue. So i'm trying to fetch it through a proxy server, but i'm receiving this error:

```
Error: AxiosError: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
```

This is the proxyServer.js:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors());

const https = require("https");
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
});

app.get("/words", async (req, res) => {
  await axios
    .get(
      `https://krdict.korean.go.kr/api/search?certkey_no=4013&key=${API_KEY}&type_search=search&part=word&q=%EB%82%98%EB%AC%B4&sort=dict`,
      { agent }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Response:", response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("Error:", error));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on port 3000"));
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs?noredirect=1&lq=1 (the second one solved my problem)

Answer (score -1):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import https from 'https'
import { API_HOST } from './config'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_HOST,
})

instance.defaults.httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
})

instance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
        return config
    },
    (error) => {
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)
```

I used this configuration.
This solved my problem.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.