# While uploading image files to cloudinary I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

[image]

### This error is related to node and using https module with new certificates also doesn't work...

##### solution is unclear how to resolve this

signing new certificates generated by openssl also doesn't work for me

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample and some more information about your development environment (local, Vercel, etc)? Without seeing what your code looks like it's incredibly difficult to pinpoint a cause and resolution.

Comment: i have simple function to upload files and single route handling it and also this error does not say anything about upload

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that certificate chain is incomplete, you have to handle these errors in node-js if `cloudinary` package is not handling it.

There are many workaround for this, Secure and Unsecure aswell for eg:

`process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0`

It disables any security that TLS provides.
It's dangerous to use.

People have provided more details solution as how to do this in safe way [Unable to verify leaf signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature) , and [unable to verify certificate nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673587/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate-in-nodejs)

Comment: I've been working on this project from one month and got this error from no where do you know possible reason for its occurrence.

Comment: Okay so basically you are using cloudinary backend SDK libraries which provide a wrapper for the Upload API, here request building and authentication are handled automatically. So something might have went wrong in there wrapper function and cloudinary npm package is not updated to handle that. What you can do is instead of using uploader function manually make a post request to cloudinary API [here's how](https://soshace.com/how-to-upload-images-and-videos-to-cloudinary-in-your-node-js-application-step-by-step-tutorial/)

Comment: the problem is related to node not cloudinary. I tried to use new ssl certificates but it is not working as well.

Comment: Without a code sample, we're not going to be able to tell you what in your code needs changing. I strongly recommend updating your question's description to include the code you're running, or a CodeSandbox link if that makes more sense. Best of luck! :)