# When I try to install mui/lab it gives UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE and 403 forbidden error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, material-ui

When I try to install mui/lab it gives:

```
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://pkg.csb.dev/mui/mui-x/commit/1f23b33d/@mui/x-tree-view failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I tried setting strict-ssl to false . I get the following error:

```
26.16 npm ERR! code E403
26.16 npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://pkg.csb.dev/mui/mui-x/commit/1f23b33d/@mui/x-tree-view
26.16 npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
26.16 npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
26.16 npm ERR! 403 
26.16 npm ERR! 403 It was specified as a dependency of '@mui/lab'
26.16 npm ERR! 403 
26.19 
26.19 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
26.19 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-09-07T10_50_32_206Z-debug.log
```

Node version:

```
14.18.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to verify leaf signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082893/unable-to-verify-leaf-signature)

Comment: Nope, the mentioned question not answer my question.

Comment: I'm getting the same 403 without setting strict SSL to false (on node v18 via yarn). Looks like my company's corporate firewall is blocking access to it, when using a browser I get: `Access to the following file has been blocked according to your corporate policy. It may contain a virus, be potentially unsafe or otherwise inappropriate. Please contact your administrator for assistance.` I don't understand why it's trying to reach that domain, why isn't it via `registry.npmjs.org`?