# nodemon index.js not working in windows but works on macOS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

```
import express from "express";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get("https://secrets-api.appbrewery.com/random");
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      secret: result.data.secret,
      user: result.data.username,
    });
  } catch (error){
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this code works fine on MacOS but doesn't run on windows pc
i am not getting a error in TERMINAL, but in browser page doesn't load.

Comment: Have you tried commenting out your try catch block and replace it with a 200 response just to see if that's even working

Comment: code is working fine on MacOS, but doesn't work on windows

Comment: can you post the log of the error too?

Comment: >>   code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE',iosError: unable to verify the first certificate

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263280/17665766) can help you

Comment: i think this is a issue with antivirus software